# from linq projection into keyvalue pair

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want from json action result to return Id and Name property from certain object, so I decided to use KeyValuePair data type.

My question is how to inject data into KeyValuePair varaible from linq projection, for example

```
int id = 100;
string name = "john";
var data = repository.FindById(id);
var result = new KeyValuePair<int, string>();
result = data.Where(c=>c.Name == name)        
   .Select(x=>.x.Id)
   .Select(a=>a.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `Select` the `KeyValuePair` in your query.

```
int id = 100;
string name = "john";
var data = repository.FindById(id);
var result = data.Where(c=>c.Name == name)        
   .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int,string>(x.Id, x.Name))
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicit way - maybe better readable - would be

```
var kv = new KeyValuePair<int, string> 
{
    Key = data.Where(c => c.Name == name).Select(x =>.x.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
    Value = data.Where(c => c.Name == name).Select(a => a.Name).FirstOrDefault()
};
```